# How to prevent closing expansion panel from vuetify 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

How do I prevent to close the expansion panel when the user click on erase button inside the v-slot:actions="{ expanded }" tag?

```
    <v-expansion-panels>
        <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-title>
                Buscador
                <template v-slot:actions="{ expanded }">
                    <v-icon :color="!expanded ? 'teal' : ''">{{ expanded ? 'mdi-minus' : 'mdi-plus' }}</v-icon>
                    <v-icon class="ml-2" @click="limpiarBuscador">mdi-eraser</v-icon>
                </template>
            </v-expansion-panel-title>
            <v-expansion-panel-text>
<!-- SOME INFO -->
            </v-expansion-panel-text>
        </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
```

Comment: Add a .stop on your click : @click.stop="limpiarBuscador"